# My friends wanted to kick out our lecturer

Tags: lecturer

At my university, there is a lecturer that my friends dislike. I think he is a genius and really knows algorithms and programming. He is easily accessible and will talk with everyone. However, some of my friends dislike him because his teaching method. He often gives difficult questions and we had troubles on his exam. They created a petition to remove him. I hope he is not kicked out by them. What should I do?

Comment: I understand your question as that you would like to support your instructor. If that is the case, you could consider leaving positive feedback with those higher up - his direct boss, say -, as well as mentioning it in the course evaluation. If you feel strongly enough about this, you could of course start a counter petition signed by people who agree with you.

Comment: I would go to the lecturer and tell him you support him. And be ready to support him if his case is brought up to the faculty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instructor has issues with teaching then hopefully this will be brought up to the department and they can work with him to improve his teaching.

As far as your question about what you should do, just continue through the course as you would any other. If at any time you feel like the instructor isn't providing you an adequate education, then try to have a meeting with him before politely bringing it up with the department.

Comment: OP should comment, but I read the question as OP wanting the exact opposite (see comment above).

Comment: @gnometorule In that case, my advice is the same. Continue as usual. If he isn't an adequate teacher for the other students then the department should hopefully intervene.

Comment: I will investigate again about my lecturer's doing. I think that he is a good lecturer.

Comment: @OliviaOlgaClarissa While you may think so, multiple students disagree so they should seek intervention from the department if they feel that is needed.

Comment: Should I ask department to intervene? I don't want my junior later do the same thing with him.

Comment: @OliviaOlgaClarissa I would not since there is nothing for you to do or say (since you are fine with the instructor). If the other students have an issue, it is their business and will sort it out.

Comment: @AustinHenley I disagree. Proactive praising of the lecturer's teaching (possibly without link to the petition) may create a counterbalance to make clear that not everybody agrees once the petition comes through. Otherwise, only the negative voices will be heard. I know of a course where a single (but very negative) comment seriously damaged the relation between a lecturer and her class. I have reasons to suspect it would not have happened if proactive support had been demonstrated. Let the upper echelons know your praises.